# alternative to tf_frozen_model in tensorflowjs_converter

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter, tensorflowjs

I am new to tensorflow and installed the current tensorflowjs(1.1.2) through pip, since I want to convert a frozen inference graph (`.pb`) to a tensorflowjs file (`--output_format=tensorflowjs`). I followed a tutorial where `--input_format=tf_frozen_model` is suggested, this version of tensorflowjs, however is not supporting such option anymore and returns an error message `error:argument --input_format: invalid choice: 'tf_frozen_model'`. Has this option been replaced completely, or only renamed?
I tried to install version `tensorflowjs v.0.8.0`, which resulted in a bunch of ImportErrors (for Keras) and dependency conflicts. Do I miss something here?

Comment: I managed to get pass the Keras dependecy conflicts. Now I am getting tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: /mobilenet/frozen_model.pb : Access is denied.
; Input/output error

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new virtual environment and install tensorflowjs 0.8.6 using command:  pip install tensorflowjs==0.8.6
2. further model can be converted using:  tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_json=true --output_node_names='MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1' --saved_model_tags=serve \
   /mobilenet/frozen_model.pb /mobilenet/web_model
3. refer:https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of the `tensorflowjs` package no longer convert from `frozen models`. From https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter:

> Note: If you want to convert TensorFlow frozen model or session
> bundle, you can install older versions of the tensorflowjs pip
> package, i.e. pip install tensorflowjs==0.8.6

.
Hope it helps.